# Is it possible to change DOM Event from Click to Mouseenter for specific group of elements via userscript in Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, youtube, event-listener, tampermonkey, userscripts

Pre-conditions: PC, Chrome based Browser, be on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/), be logged in to YouTube.

There are videos on YouTube main page, which are recommended to user. If user is not interested in certain video he must:

1. Hover cursor over video area - [Three dots button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1KrX.png) will appear
2. Click on three dots button - [Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gutj.png) will appear
3. Click not interested button - Video will be removed from feed

I want change those steps with userscript in Tampermonkey to:

1. Hover cursor over video area - [Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Gutj.png) will appear
2. Click not interested button - Video will be removed from feed

**My questions are**:

1. Is it possible to change DOM Event from Click to Mouseenter for specific group of elements via userscript in Tampermonkey?
2. Where can I find info/examples how to do it?

Comment: Find the element, then `element.addEventListener('mouseover', event => event.target.click()); element.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => event.target.click());`. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

It's not best solution, it affects only videos which are loaded at start of the page.

```
(async () => {
    let i = 1;
    while (i != 0) {
        await sleep(1);
        i++;
        if (i > 100) {
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('yt-icon-button#button.dropdown-trigger.style-scope.ytd-menu-renderer');
            elements.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseover', event => event.target.click()));
            i = 0;
        }
    }
})();
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, ms);
    })
}
```

Where the main part is:

```
// Selecting all elemets on page to add new eventlistener
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('yt-icon-button#button.dropdown-trigger.style-scope.ytd-menu-renderer'); 
// Adding new evenlistener which on Mouseover performs Click
elements.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseover', event => event.target.click()));
```

Thanks [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721209/is-it-possible-to-change-dom-event-from-click-to-mouseenter-for-specific-group-o/65749837#comment116218484_65721209) for the idea